# Having a hard time printing out stars in java

Tags: java

I am having a hard time trying to print out a number of stars based on what is being passed to those methods that are responsible for printing them. Here is the code that I worked on so far. I added comments to those areas I am not sure about what to do. I am trying to follow everything that the Purpose of the methods ask of me. But I have been unsuccessful in doing so.

```
public class Stars
{
  private static final int MAX_STARS = 15;
  private static String BAR_REP = "*";
  private static DecimalFormat valueFormatter = new DecimalFormat("00.00");
  private static DecimalFormat indexFormatter = new DecimalFormat("000");

  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
     processQuestionData("5,25,30,36,46");
  }

 public static void processQuestionData(String data)
 {
    double[] values = fillArray(data);
    double max = findMax(values);

    drawBar(values, max); // This won't work but I have to pass 2 double values.   
 }

 /**
 * PURPOSE: accepts a String data containing a comma separated list
 *          and converts it into an array of double values
 *
 *  @param String data - comma separated string containing double data
 *
 *  @return double [] - array containing the data extracted from data
 */

  public static double[] fillArray(String data)
  {
    String[] answers = data.split(",");
    double[] values = new double[answers.length];

    for (int index = 0; index < answers.length; index++)
    {
        values[index] = Double.parseDouble(answers[index]);
    }

    return values;
  }

 /**
 * PURPOSE: given a an array of double values find the largest item
 *
 *  @param double[] items - an array of double data
 *
 *  @return double the largest item in the array
 */
 public static double findMax(double[] items)
 {
    double maxValue = items[0];

    for(int index = 0; index < items.length; index++)
    {
        if (items[index] > maxValue)
        {
            maxValue = items[index];
        }
    }

    return maxValue;
 }

 **
 * PURPOSE: given a value and a max as double type arguments,
 *          draws a bar using '*' representing the value, scaled
 *          so that max value would equal the constant MAX_STARS
 *
 * @param double value - the value to be displayed by the bar in the chart
 * @param double max   - the max value for the bar chart
 */
 public static void drawBar(double value, double max )
 {
    double correctRatio = (value / max) * MAX_STARS;

    if (correctRatio == MAX_STARS)
    {
        for (int index = 0; index < max; index++)
        {
            System.out.print(BAR_REP);
        }
    }

    else if (correctRatio < MAX_STARS)
    {
       for (int index = 0; index < max; index++)
       {
          System.out.print(BAR_REP);
       }
    }
 }

}
```

Output should be this...

```
 *
 ********
 *********
 ***************
```

1st one is 1. Got that by (5 / 46) * 15

2nd one is 8. Found by (25/46) * 15

And so on....

How can I fix my code to exactly that? I believe that the major problem lies in calling the drawBar method and within the drawBar method itself. I don't think that the other methods are improperly coded.

Comment: This is perhaps one of the most frequently asked questions.  Printing stars.

Comment: Run your program through a debugger.  Is it fair to expect others to debug your code?

Comment: What is "cake" in your processQuestionData method. Are you sure you don't have some simple syntax errors?

Answer (score 0):

Why not provide a "star bar" constant that has the maximum number of stars present, and use a substring of that constant to get the number you want (  `myStars = C_STARBAR.substring(0,n)` where n is the number of stars .. account for not going over maximum stars of course!

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature and code of `drawBar` method like below. You will get your expected output.

```
public class Stars {
  private static final int MAX_STARS = 15;
  private static String BAR_REP = "*";  

  public static void main (String[] args){
     processQuestionData("5,25,30,36,46");
  }

  public static void processQuestionData(String data) {
     double[] values = fillArray(data);
     double max = findMax(values);

     drawBar(values, max); 
  }

  public static double[] fillArray(String data) {
     String[] answers = data.split(",");
     double[] values = new double[answers.length];

     for (int index = 0; index < answers.length; index++) {
       values[index] = Double.parseDouble(answers[index]);
     }

    return values;
 }


 public static double findMax(double[] items) {
   double maxValue = items[0];

   for(int index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
     if (items[index] > maxValue) {
        maxValue = items[index];
     }
   }
 return maxValue;
 }


 public static void drawBar(double[] values, double max ) {  

 for(int count=0;count<values.length;count++) {      
     double value = values[count];   
     int correctRatio = (int)((value / max) * MAX_STARS);

     for(int stars=1;stars<=correctRatio;stars++){
         System.out.print(BAR_REP);
     }
     System.out.println();
 }
 }

}
```